# pandas `MiltiIndex` - `where` is not supported for MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

Hi I want to replace index values by some other values if the condition is satisfied (keeping `index.names` unctouched). The following works for `Index`:

```
df.index = df.index.where(~df.index.isin(indicesToReplace), newIndices)
```

However for `MultiIndex` I got `where is not supported for MultiIndex operations`. What other function can I use?